# Ruby factorial function explained?

Tags: ruby, factorial

```
#This function should return n!
def factorial(n)
  return nil if n < 0
  n == 0 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1)
end
```

Just starting out and this function is blowing my mind I would write this function like this:

```
def factorial(n)
  result = 1

  if n == 0 
    return 1
  end

  while n > 0
    result *= n
    n -= 1
  end
  return result
end
```

I understande the short hand for the if/else statement. What I dont understand is using n*factorial(n-1) inside the function itself.

It looks like the factorial function is called inside the factorial function, but that can't be whats going on right?

Comment: That is in fact what is going on here. This is a recursive approach to computing factorials.

Comment: that is exactly whats going on. the `factorial` function is being called inside itself.

Comment: "To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion."

Comment: Thanks guys just the answer I was looking for. Now that I know what its called i'll be sure to look into recursion further.

Answer (score 2):

Factorial(5) evaluates to

```
5 * factorial(4)
```

factorial(4) evaluates to

```
4 * factorial(3)
```

factorial(3) evaluates to

```
3 * factorial(2)
```

factorial(2) evaluates to

```
2 * factorial(1)
```

factorial(1) evaluates to 1 because 1 <= 1

Substituting values appropriately results in

```
5 * factorial(4)
5 * 4 * factorial(3)
5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

It's called recursion, the method is calling itself each time it evaluates until it meets the base case of 1 which is what this statement is doing: `n == 0 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1)`
:)

Comment: Clear and to the point, Thanks!

Comment: @RaSedg -  Would appreciate if you mark it as the answer if you have a moment.